# Requests form submit, no name for image

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm trying to submit a form through requests but I cannot seem to find a way to post the image.

Here are the browser requests:

```
-----------------------------20194539421983846218651111117
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_id"

968754
-----------------------------20194539421983846218651111117
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="position"

1
-----------------------------20194539421983846218651111117
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadimg"; filename="sunny_vale.jpg"

Content-Type: image/jpeg
[...]
ÿØÿà
[...]
```

This is how my requests looks like:

```
imgdata = {
    'image_id': "968754",
    'position': '1',
    'name': 'uploadimg',
    'filename': 'sunny_vale.jpg',
}
```

But I cannot seem to understand where to add the image content, to which key from the dictionary.

Edit:
My current code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
s.headers.update({"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
pic = open('/home/mint_user/Desktop/sunny_vale.jpg', 'rb').read()
imgdata = {
    'image_id': '968754',
    'position': '1',
    'uploadimg': pic,
    'filename': 'sunny_vale.jpg'
}

s.post('http://127.0.0.1/captcha_ocr/letters/ajax', imgdata)
```

And image uploader returns error, however when I do it by browser, works perfectly.

Comment: Could you please provide samples of your pre-existing code?

Comment: @RedSmoke done!

Comment: Are you sending pic as an object ?? if it is then you should write file upload image?
Can you share your code snippet of upload

Comment: Your post request doesn't contain the multipart form data that You have when you do it by a browser